# Displaying SVG images

Tags: c#, svg, razor, model-view-controller

I have some SVG files stored in a database as a string. What would be the best way to display these images on a razor view template?

I was hoping to just display the string directly

something like

```
<div>
    @Model.Icon
</div>
```

but when I do this quotation marks are placed around the content so the image doesnt display

example svg format is

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 21.0.2, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 127.4 72.2" style="enable-background:new 0 0 127.4 72.2;" xml:space="preserve">
<title>Artboard 2 copy 11</title>
<path d="M126.3,7v10.5c1.3,7.7,1.5,18.2,0.2,29.7c-0.9,8.5-2.6,16.8-5.1,24.9h-7l-4.7,0h-8.7c-1,0-1.8-1.4-1.8-3.1l0,0
    c0-1.7,0.8-3.1,1.8-3.1h1.8c1.2-4.8,2.1-9.6,2.8-14.5h-1.9c-2.8-0.2-5.1-2.5-5.1-5.3l-0.1-11.8H87.1c-9.7,0-19.8-3.3-22.5-11.3h-7
    c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1.1v-0.6H44.9v-3.6h-5.4c-1.2-2.6-3.3-3.1-7.1-3.7c-0.1,0,4.1,1.4,4,3.7h-6.1c-1.2-2.6-3.4-3.1-7.1-3.8
    c-0.1,0,4.1,1.4,4,3.7h-6.1c-1.2-2.6-3.4-3.1-7.1-3.7c-0.1,0,4.1,1.4,4,3.7h-5.6c-1.2-2.6-3.4-3.1-7.1-3.7c-0.1,0,4.1,1.4,4,3.7H4.4
    c-0.9-1.8-2.2-2.6-4.4-3.2v-1.3h44.9V9.6h11.7V9c0-0.6,0.4-1.1,1-1.1h6.5C67.3-3.2,126.3-1.8,126.3,7z M106.1,48.7
    c0.1-0.5,0.1-0.9,0.2-1.4c0.5-4.5,0.8-8.8,0.8-12.9h-5.6l0.1,11.8c0,1.1,0.8,2.1,1.8,2.4c0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.5,0.1H106.1z"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use :

```
@Html.Raw(Model.Icon)
```